# Swift: How to configure a tableview with multiple sections dynamically using JSON data

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, model

I'm trying to populate a dynamic UITableView with multiple sections using JSON data retrieved from an endpoint on the server.

The tableview is supposed to display a list of a user's projects, organized by team, with up to 5 recent projects from any team at the top.

**However, I'm having trouble populating the teams (sections) with their projects due to the complex JSON returned. I know I have to compare the project's team ID to the team's team ID so identify if that project belongs to that team. But I'm stuck on the next step: how can I store all the projects that belong to a team and then index this data structure to display the team name for the section title and then the projects for that given team.**

What I've tried to do so far:

1. Loop through each project fetched from the endpoint.
2. Check if the current project's team ID matches the current team's team ID.
3. If they match, add that project to that team

   ```
   // Loop through each project
   for project in projects {
       // If the current project belongs to the current team
       if project.relationships.team.id == teams[section - 1].id {
           // Add the project to that team

       }

   }
   ```

The recent section (first section at the top) is reserved for a list of table view cells which include a title (project's name) and the subtitle (the team in which the project is contained).

The tableview must have 1 section for each team, with each displaying the team's projects. The tableview cells should contain a title that displays the project's name.

Below is a sample JSON response of the endpoint.

**The problem I'm having is figuring out how to assign each Project to its associated Team and then indexing that data structure (I was thinking a 2-dimentional array that holds an array of Teams, where each team holds an array of Projects that are associated to it).**

`included` is an array of Teams. `data` is an array of Projects.

```
{
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "teams",
      "id": "1",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Team1"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "teams",
      "id": "2",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Team2"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "teams",
      "id": "3",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Team3"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "projects",
      "id": "1",
      "relationships": {
        "team": {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "teams"
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "name": "House of Cards",
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "projects",
      "id": "2",
      "relationships": {
        "team": {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "teams"
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Arrested Development",
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "projects",
      "id": "3",
      "relationships": {
        "team": {
          "id": "1",
          "type": "teams"
        }
      },
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Orange Is The New Black",
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I created a Model (and its associated Models) based on the JSON:

```
struct JSON: Codable {
    let included: [Included]
    let data: [Datum]
}
```

Here are relevant snippets of my code:

```
// This should belong in the fetchData() function to be called in viewDidLoad but I believe I need access to the `section`

    var arrProjects = [Datum]()
    // Loop through each project
    for project in projects {
        // If the current project belongs to the current team
        if project.relationships.team.id == teams[section - 1].id {
            // Add the project to that team
            arrProjects.append(project)

//                let teamName = teams[section - 1].attributes.name
//                projectsByTeam.append([teamName: arrProjects])
            //projectsByTeam[section-1] = [teamName: arrProjects]

            let teamName = teams[section - 1].attributes.name
            let team = [teamName: arrProjects]
            projectsByTeam.append(team)
        }

    }


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
self?.json = try decoder.decode(JSON.self, from: data)

guard let json = self?.json else { return }

self?.teams = json.included
self?.projects = json.data

DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}

...

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let numberOfTeams = teams?.count {
        return 1 + numberOfTeams
    }

    return 1

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    guard let projects = projects else { return 0 }
    guard let teams = teams else { return 0 }

    let numberOfProjects = projects.count

    if section == 0 {
        // Recent section
        if numberOfProjects <= 5 {
            return 0
        } else if numberOfProjects > 5 && numberOfProjects < 10 {
            return numberOfProjects - 5
        } else if numberOfProjects >= 10 {
            return 5
        }
    }

    // *NEED TO FIND THE NUMBER OF PROJECTS FOR EACH REMAINING SECTION (WHICH IS A TEAM)*
    // How to index the data structure that holds the projects for each team?

    return 0

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    guard let project = projects?[indexPath.row] else { return UITableViewCell() }

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.RecentCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! RecentTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = project.attributes.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = project.relationships.team.id

        return cell
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.ProjectCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ProjectTableViewCell
    // How to index the data structure that holds the projects for each team?
    //cell.textLabel?.text = projectsByTeam?[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Here's what the tableview structure should look like roughly:

> Section 0 - Recent
>
> - ProjectA (Team 1)
> - ProjectD (Team 2)
> - ProjectE (Team 3)
>
> Section 1 - Team 1
>
> - ProjectA
> - ProjectB
>
> Section 2 - Team 2
>
> - ProjectC
> - ProjectD
>
> Section 3 - Team 3
>
> - ProjectE
> - ProjectF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your data structure like that:

```
var teams = [[String: [Datum]]]()
for team in teams {
let teamProjects = projects.filter {$0.relationships.team.id == team.id}
let teamData = [team: [teamProjects]]
teams.append(teamData)
}
```

and in numberOfRows method:

```
 let team = teamsWithProjects[section-1]
 let teamProject = Array(team.values)[0]
 return teamProject.count
```

and in cellForRow method:

```
  let team = teamsWithProjects[indexPath.section-1]
  let teamProject = Array(team.values)[0]
  projectCell.textLabel?.text = teamProject[indexPath.row].attributes.name
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thanks but this isn't going to work in this case. (See my updated question for more clarification on what I'm trying to accomplish).

Comment: instead of hardcoding team1 and team 2, as you've shown, how can I construct these `var teams = [[String:[Project]]]()` dynamically?

Note, this line is important to make sure the project we're at in the loop, belongs to the team, before we add the project to that team:
       // If the current project belongs to the current team
        `if project.relationships.team.id == teams[section - 1].id { ...`

Comment: Thank you @Hosny - we're getting closer. If I use `var teams =  [Included: [Datum]]`, I get an error that `Included` "does not conform to protocol `Hashable`. Anyways, I decided I can use this: `var teams = [String: [Datum]]`. But when I try to do: `teams.append(teamData)`, I'm getting the error: "Value of type '[String: [Datum]]' has no member 'append'. `teams` is an array of dictionaries, so I'm not sure why it's not working. Do you know why?

Comment: @diligence, No, teams is dictionary, sorry this is my fault, I updated my answer please check it, I updated to var teams = [[Included: [Datum]]].

Comment: Thanks @Hosny - I appreciate your continued help. But even when I use `var teams = [[Included: [Datum]]]`, I still get the error, "Type 'Included' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'". When I use `var teams = [[String: [Datum]]]()`, there's no error.
But, still even even with this type (looks like an Array of Dictionaries), I'm not sure if your other code will index out the correct team-project pairs. Can we connect on Skype or LinkedIn to discuss this better please? Thank you.

Comment: @diligence Sure, my Skype is elsayed.hussein13